Assistance on an $ε-δ$ proof as $x→∞$
I need to provide an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof for the following:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^2-4}{x^2-1}=1.$$
My sketch begins with for every $\epsilon>0$,there exists $M>0$ such that
$$\left|\frac{x^2-4}{x^2-1}-1\right|<\epsilon\ \text{ if }x>M.$$
Can we proceed by showing that
$$\left|\frac{x^2-4}{x^2-1}-1\right|=\frac{3}{x^2-1}<\frac{1}{x}\quad \text{ 
if }x\geq\frac{10}{3}?$$
Then, choose $M>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ so that
$$\left|\frac{x^2-4}{x^2-1}-1\right|<\frac{1}{x}<\frac{1}{M}<\epsilon\quad \text{ if }x>M.$$
Is my third step legal? Thanks.

As long as you make sure that $M$ is simultaneously larger than $\frac 1\epsilon$ and also larger than $\frac{10}3$, rather than just larger than $\frac1\epsilon$. This is required for the leftmost inequality in your final chain of inequalities to hold.

To solve this problem, can I let M > max{1/ε, 10/3}?

@Nicholas Yes. You can even let it be equal to that maximum, technically.
